# Cant able to copy image from an external url to my server

Tags: php, mysql, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

I am trying to copy a bunch of image file links store in mysql data from one server to another server, well kind of like a cron job running in the background which checks for external links and copy it to the server. Few links which shows when viewing manually works but when i try to copy the file through php code nothing happens. It just outputs empty string.

Below are few links which i try to copy to my server.

1. http://crm.propspace.com/watermark?c_id=1646&l_id=2300187&aid=1444765&id=14181282100524636&image=09_12_2014-16_53_34-1646-b15d08432d253ac710dc7bea47bf67c9.png
2. http://crm.propspace.com/watermark?c_id=1646&l_id=2257894&aid=1444765&id=14169037278702926&image=25_11_2014-12_29_24-1646-67974878d8b7abd86d86c93527e15ebd.jpg
3. http://crm.propspace.com/watermark?c_id=1646&l_id=2257894&aid=1444765&id=14169037278702926&image=25_11_2014-12_29_31-1646-0cf46efe5b2f89214001a2e050353736.jpg
4. http://crm.propspace.com/watermark?c_id=1646&l_id=2282465&aid=1444765&id=14176053840492751&image=03_12_2014-16_36_29-1646-46cd5f89122e6899f8185e20bd942dd7.png

The links opens up and show the image, but when i try to copy through php code i get just empty data. I tried all types of methods to copy the image like

```
1. copy()
2. fopen()
3. file_get_contents()
4. curl_init()
```

but everything ended up with empty string or data. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Methods used for retrieving image file

```
$img_link       =   "image from link";
$upload_link    =   "image to save link";


Method 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$img_cont       =   file_get_contents($img_link);
file_put_contents($upload_link, $img_cont);



Method 2 - (This method gives me an image with 0 bytes)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
copy($img_link, $upload_link);


Method 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$img_file   =   fopen($img_link, 'r');
$img_data   =   '';
while($chunk = fread($img_file, 8192))
$img_data   .=  $chunk;
fclose($img_file);


Method 4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$img_stream =   fopen($img_link, 'r');
$img_data   =   stream_get_contents($img_stream);
fclose($img_stream);


Method 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$referer    =   "http://www.propspace.com/"
$headers    =   array(
    'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
);

// Initialize cURL Connection
$conn           =   curl_init();

// Set cURL Options
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_URL, $img_link);

// Add Headers
if(is_array($headers) && count($headers) > 0){
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}

// Add References
if($reference != "")
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reference);

// Other Options
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

// Execute Request
$img_cont       =   curl_exec($conn);
```

Thank you.

> Update: Just now found a thing which is making the image to show 0 size. It is accessible only from dubai or UAE networks. How can I make it work though?

Comment: can u add your code?

Comment: plz check now i have mentioned the methods which i used...

Comment: if u having problem in putting content on server then it can b permissions issue, mean u have to set 777 for folder where u trying to save image on server.

Comment: no that is not an issue... the issue is on reading image file from some links like which i mentioned above in my post...

Comment: i am not able to access them in browser.

Comment: i found the issue... it is checking ip or date locale (i believe) for access only within UAE.. i tried connecting to other server (eg: london) through vpn and checked it... eevn i am not getting the image...now is it possible to tell the server its from UAE?

Answer (score 0):

You try to download generic images that are only accessible if you are logged in propperly. You would have to "log in" with your server and then you may be able to do this. I did this once with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php).

Comment: well this images can be accessed without login... even i tried using cURL but what i get is empty string/data...

Comment: We cannot access your urls. They are 0 size images. Also you don't seem to use cookies in your curl, and no login request.

Comment: just now found a thing which is making the image to show 0 size. It is accessible only from dubai or UAE networks.. if i try connecting to other server through vpn even im getting the same 0 size image... is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: You would have to use a proxy, but you'll have to find a reliable one. And I do not know how to use proxies via php.

Answer (score 0):

Well it could have many reasons. Did you get any warnings/errors?
Maybe "allow_url_fopen" in your php.ini is set to "off"

Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: i did check for "allow_url_fopen" and it is in "On" state... And no warnings or errors, thats the wierd part.... :D

Answer (score 0):

i have used this method to copy external images

```
public function update_pics($url)
    {

            $image_array=explode('/',$url);
            if($image_array[0]!='http:')
            {
                $url='http:'.$url;
            }
              $image_name=strtolower($image_array[count($image_array)-1]);
            $supported_image = array(
                'gif',
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png'
            );
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if (!in_array($ext, $supported_image)) {
                $image_name=$image_name.'.jpg';
            } 
            if(copy($url, './uploads/'.$image_name))
            {

                $target = 'uploads/';
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $target.$image_name;
                $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $config['width'] = $width;
                $config['height'] = $height;    
                $config['new_image'] = $target.$image_name;     
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                $this->image_lib->clear();
            }       
    }
```